# Laravel artisan serve with PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS

Tags: php, laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

How can i use PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS to use php in built development server to work as multi threaded? I had tried with adding environment variable in docker-composer.yaml (using sail). But it seems not working with `php artisan serve`.

Initial problem was with the guzzle cant make request to localhost if it is ran from PHP built in server.

Answer (score 4):

not sure if you figured this out, but after a lot of hair pulling.. Basically you need to override the default artisan serve command (which is a wrapper around the `php -S` command):

- publish the sail docker files `sail artisan sail:publish`
- edit the `./docker/8.0/supervisord.conf`

change from

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS /var/www/html/artisan serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

to

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true
user=root
logfile=/var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log
pidfile=/var/run/supervisord.pid

[program:php]
directory=/var/www/html/public
command=/usr/bin/php -d variables_order=EGPCS -S 0.0.0.0:80 /var/www/html/server.php
user=sail
environment=LARAVEL_SAIL="1",PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS="10"
stdout_logfile=/dev/stdout
stdout_logfile_maxbytes=0
stderr_logfile=/dev/stderr
stderr_logfile_maxbytes=0
```

Rebuild the docker stuff with `sail build --no-cache` and then `sail up`

To explain a few things, we need to set the supervisord directory to the root directory else assets like css and js wont be found. then we run the server.php file in the same way as the `artisan serve` command does, as per the [ServeCommand](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/ServeCommand.php). Lastly we have set the environment to have the PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS variable and set it to 10.

### EDIT:

Whilst this approach does work, no site assets (css/js etc) are cached and result is slow page loads. I have managed to use the original artisan serve command and set the PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS in the environment; however the `artisan server` command just ignores it and only initials 1 PHP process.

### Edit 2:

So after a bit more digging, the `artisan serve` command would loop over the `.env` values and pass them in as environment variables. However, all values would be false unless the key was either APP_ENV or LARAVEL_SAIL.

I have made a [PR](https://github.com/laravel/framework/compare/8.x...scott-davidjones:patch-1) to also include `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS` as an allowed variable - this, if accepted, will allow you to simply add the variable to your `.env` file and it should all work as expected.

Comment: I had tried with editing default sail command but it was not reflecting. Sail seems overkill to me. I noticed sailed app are slower specifically for DB connections. Also sail is only for development, so either way still it need to be prepared for production. So overall I have stopped using sail in development. Currently doing it normal way. Though I will try your way to test things up.

Comment: agreed, sail is only for local development only. it does remove the hassle of installing platform dependant software though. which can speed up development time.

Answer (score 2):

Try below command

```
PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=2 php artisan serve
```

Answer (score 1):

As of Laravel 9 [you can](https://github.com/laravel/framework/commit/747e1ade99de78f313d2f724f915d28a67cafdd4#diff-6731b6d867fedc0669bc319f7fa9f091516f0b1dac93f644e9a2140472b9d98dR106) just add `PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS` variable right to your `.env` to increase the number of workers spawned by PHP's built-in server (which is used under the hood in Laravel Sail)

```
// .env
// Process 3 requests at a time
PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a cli command? Like, eg:

php artisan make:template

Is it something like that?
If this is the case, you will need to use Artisan Console. Here is the link to oficial documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/artisan

Comment: No. I want PHP development server to work as multithreded with php artisan serve. As per doc adding PHP_CLI_SERVER_WORKERS to environment variable should work. But i am not sure why its not working.